# Make sure database that is in BCNF

Tags: mysql, database, bcnf

I have designed a database and as I made it its in BCNF now, but how I can be sure that it is really in BCNF, how i can check it? I know what is BCNF but I just want to know is there any method or a way to check it or make sure that is in BCNF. I have tried with some queries but I am not sure is it enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it explicitly and check by the uusual way ie, you need to find all the candidate keys in your table and if all the FD(*functional dependency*) satisfy the definition.